# Typescript Return Nested Object Reference

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have an array of customer objects, each with an array of invoice objects, and each invoice has an array of invoice_items.

Given an invoice_item_guid - I'd like to return the 1 unique invoice_item object with the specific GUID.

I do not know the customer or the invoice and I'd like to NOT create a bunch of for loops.

For example:

> **customer**
>
> customerid
>
> **invoices**
>
> > invoiceid
> >
> > **invoice_items**
> >
> > > invoice_item_guid
> > >
> > > invoice_item_id
> > >
> > > invoice_item_qty

I planned to do something like a compound FIND, sorta like this:

```
var i: invoice_item;
i = this.customers.find(c => c.invoices).find(inv => inv.invoice_items).find(item => item.invoice_item_guid === "someguid");
```

At best, I get a customer object back - but I really want to drill deeper and get the invoice_item object (not the customer) back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Array.reduce and Array.map to extract the invoice_items array and use Array.find on that.

```
let i = this.customers
  .reduce((items, customer) => {
    return items.concat(...customer.invoices
      .map(invoice => invoice.invoice_items));
  }, [])
  .find(item => item.invoice_item_guid === 'someguid');
```

Here is a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0mnjhpgq/) of this solution.

Comment: "i" is coming back as undefined.

Comment: Thats because the reduce returns something like this  

`
[
    [
        [
            {
                "invoiceItemGuid": 1
            }
        ]
    ]
]
`
items[invoices[invoice_items[item]]]

and hence fails to find it.

Comment: Apologies, I've fixed the issue with my example. I was pushing an array which was generated the results you were seeing. concat works better in this case.

Comment: The concat version still won't work, it'll still return an array inside an array.

Checkout my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59763640/6146021 I've added a dummy array, which might help you.

Answer (score 1):

I made a dummy array based on your description.

The following solution should work but may not be the most optimal way of doing it.

```js
const customers = [{
    customerId: 1,
    invoices: [{
        invoiceId: 1,
        invoiceItems: [{
            invoiceItemGuid: 1
        }]
    }]
},
{
    customerId: 2,
    invoices: [{
        invoiceId: 2,
        invoiceItems: [{
            invoiceItemGuid: 2
        }]
    }]
}
]

const item = customers.flatMap(customer => customer.invoices).flatMap(invoice => invoice.invoiceItems).find(item => item.invoiceItemGuid === 2)

console.log(item)
```

Comment: I like the elegant solution, but I am getting an error. It looks like flatMap is not yet supported (at least by my browser). Is this something new?

Comment: If you still have issues with flatMap support, you can use flatMap from lodash, https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#flatMap

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Updated answer, using the '`reduce` and `find` methods.

```js
const findInvoiceItem = (data) => data
  .reduce(
    (acc, curr) => [
      ...acc,
      ...curr.invoices.reduce((acc_rec, curr_rec) => [
        ...acc_rec, 
        ...curr_rec.invoice_items], [])
    ],
    []
  )
  .find(item => item.invoice_item_guid === "someguid");


const customers = [
  {
    customerid: 1,
    invoices: [
      {
        invoiceid: 1,
        invoice_items: [
          {
            invoice_item_id: 1,
            invoice_item_qty: 2,
            invoice_item_guid: "tempguid"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    customerid: 2,
    invoices: [
      {
        invoiceid: 2,
        invoice_items: [
          {
            invoice_item_id: 2,
            invoice_item_qty: 4,
            invoice_item_guid: "someguid"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];


console.log(findInvoiceItem(customers));
```

Comment: Please re-read the original request - I am trying to avoid FOR loops.

Comment: my @DaveP, I just updated answer without using for loops and use reduce methods.